# Query abbreviation TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM [user] WHERE [rank] = 1
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM [user] WHERE [rank] = 2
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM [user] WHERE [rank] = 3
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM [user] WHERE [rank] = 4
```

How can I shorten the question?

Comment: So, do you want to put that into one select statement? Is that what you mean?

Comment: I am not sure what the question so I couldn't begin to help you shorten it. Can you try to explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: @SeanLange if you are able to shorten that *question* as requested, not the *script* i'd be utterly impressed :)

Comment: @scsimon - "shorten question"? or maybe "question shorter"? LOL

Comment: Immediately press the negatives :) WEI_DBA solved!

Comment: FWIW, I didn't downvote this. Hopefully you will realize that you need to provide some details about what you are trying to do. Even as simple as "Is it possible to retrieve all 4 values in a single query?" would have been a huge leap in making this question better.

Comment: I apologize, I will be more careful.

Comment: One of the best things about Stackoverflow is that it not only allows people to answer your questions, but your questions and their answers also act as documentation and references for many people in the future who will have similar questions to you. It is always good to have a very structured, easy-to-understand question, and often times it's not a very hard thing to do. I would suggest you update the question, especially now that it's solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. From what you explained.

```
SELECT [rank], COUNT(id) 
FROM [user] 
WHERE [rank] BETWEEN 1 AND 4
GROUP BY [rank]
```

Comment: Given the extremely vague "question" this is about the only thing that makes sense. Well guessed!!!